# Typescript - Converting a Map to a comma separated string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a map that I'm converting a specific string format using:

```
let content = "";
let myMap = new Map().set('a', 1).set('b', 2).set('c', 3);
```

```
myMap.forEach((value: string, key: number) => {
   content += `${key}: ${value}, `;
});
```

However this will leave a comma at the end.

Is there some other way? e.g. to be able to use `join`?

Thanks,

Comment: can you add expected output ???

Comment: You can add condition i:e if the index(key) is equal to myMap.length - 1 then don't append comma.

Comment: Well, e.g. `[...myMap].map(([k, v]) => \`${k}: ${v}\`).join(", ");` works.

Comment: @ASDFGerte please post that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
Object.keys(myMap).map(data => [data, myMap[data]]).map(([k, v]) => `${k}:${v}`).join(', ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the map to an array, and then use `join` after a quick transformation:

```js
let myMap = new Map().set('a', 1).set('b', 2).set('c', 3);
let str = [...myMap].map(([k, v]) => `${k}: ${v}`).join(", ");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `join`

```
let content = []; // array
let myMap = new Map().set('a', 1).set('b', 2).set('c', 3);

myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
   content.push(`${key}: ${value}`); // push all elts into the array
});
```

`content` is now an array `["a: 1", "b: 2", "c: 3"]`

use join to convert it to a comma separated string

```
content = content.join();
```

desired output `"a: 1,b: 2,c: 3"`